# Twilio How to received message

Tags: c#, .net-core, twilio

I am doing the WhatsApp Bot with ASP.Net Core and Twilio. I follow the sample code from the documentation and set the sandbox for when message come in.

I able to send the message but the message received part, I cant get the user input. The parameter is empty.

I get  11200 - HTTP retrieval failure message at twilio debugger.
Can I know how to get the message Info that send by user?

```
        [Route("api/[controller]")]
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("Home/SendMessage")]
        public ActionResult SendMessage()
        {
            var accountSid = "***********";
            var authToken = "************";

            TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);
            var to = new PhoneNumber("whatsapp:+***********");
            var from = new PhoneNumber("whatsapp:+***********");
            var message = MessageResource.Create(
                to: to,
                from: from,
                body: "Hi. Success.");

            return Content(message.Sid);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("Home/ReceivedMessage")]
        public TwiMLResult ReceivedMessage(SmsRequest Body)
            {
           var twiml = new MessagingResponse();
            var message = twiml.Message($"Hello {Body}. You said {Body}");
            return TwiML(message);
        }
```

Comment: An 11200 error is an indicator of a connection failure between Twilio and your service. When Twilio requests a page from your server, we wait a maximum of 15 seconds for a response. A connection failure will occur if no response is returned in that time. Here is the [connection configuration](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/webhooks/webhooks-connection-overrides).

Comment: Suddenly it work...Thanks. But now the new problem is post always get null value.

Comment: How do you send these values from client, can you share your capture?

Comment: Sorry for late reply... I already solved the problem by adding [FromForm] for the parameter. Thank you so much.